# How can I change the color of a worksheet's tab

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a python script that is pulling data from an external resource and adding data to a Google Sheet. For the most part I have everything working, except I'd like to change the color of a tab to signify the script status.

The whole process starts by duplicating an existing tab within the sheet. The template tab has a black highlight by default. I then want to change the black to another color to show the data collection is in progress. And when done, change the color to green or red depending on if the results of the data.

However I cannot find a working example of how to change the color. Here is what I have so far:

```py
    title = 'Duplicate'
    template_id = 1000

    sheet = open_worksheet() # does all the auth/credential work
    sheet.duplicate_sheet(template_id, insert_sheet_index=0, new_sheet_name=title)
    new_tab = sheet.worksheet(title)

    body = {
        "requests": [
            {
                "updateSheetProperties": {
                    "properties": {
                        "sheetId": 1001,
                        "title": title,
                        "tabColor": {
                            "red": 1.0,
                            "green": 0.3,
                            "blue": 0.4
                        }
                    },
                    "fields": "*"
                }
            }
        ]
    }

    try:
        res = sheet.batch_update(body)
        # res = new_tab.batch_update(body)
        pprint(res)
    except gspread.exceptions.APIError as gea:
        pprint(gea.args[0], width=100)
```

If I try running the `batch_update()` against the `new_tab` pointer I get:

```
dict(vr, range=absolute_range_name(self.title, vr['range']))
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

If I run it against the whole `sheet` I get:

```
{'code': 400,
 'message': "Invalid requests[0].updateSheetProperties: You can't delete all the rows on the sheet.",
 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}
```

How do I fix my request so that it correctly updates the single tab?

Here is a link to the [Google Sheet API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate) and [Sheet properties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#SheetProperties) where I've been looking up how the request should look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to change the tab color of Google Spreadsheet using gspread.
- You want to insert new sheet using `sheet.duplicate_sheet(template_id, insert_sheet_index=0, new_sheet_name=title)` and want to change the tab color of the new sheet.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, the sheet ID can be retrieved with `new_tab.id`. You can use this value to the request body.
- In your situation, I think that `tabColor` instead of `*` can be used as the value of `fields`.

  - I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. Because when `*` is used, other fields except for `tabColor` are also changed.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify `body` as follows and test it again.

```
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "updateSheetProperties": {
                "properties": {
                    "sheetId": new_tab.id,
                    # "title": title, # In this case, I think that this might not be required to be used.
                    "tabColor": {
                        "red": 1.0,
                        "green": 0.3,
                        "blue": 0.4
                    }
                },
                "fields": "tabColor"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batchupdate#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatesheetpropertiesrequest)

Comment: I have a follow up question. What values would you send to reset the color; in other words, remove all colors. Sending an empty "tabColor" dict as well as setting red, green, blue to 0 (or negatives) changes the color to black. I don't see any documentation on how to unset the color

Comment: @MivaScott About your new question, I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. And also, I think that your new question will be useful for other users. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Here is the [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65402464/629186)

Comment: @MivaScott Thank you for your response. I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it?