# How can I reset the color of a Google Sheet through the API

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

Building off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65333296/629186) about setting a color, I wonder how to reset/clear the color of a Google Sheet's tab.

For reference, here is how to set a color

```py
    sheet = open_worksheet() # does all the auth/credential work
    new_tab = sheet.worksheet('DemoTab')

    body = {
        "requests": [
            {
                "updateSheetProperties": {
                    "properties": {
                        "sheetId": new_tab.id,
                        "tabColor": {
                            "red": 1.0,
                            "green": 0.3,
                            "blue": 0.4
                        }
                    },
                    "fields": "tabColor"
                }
            }
        ]
    }

    try:
        res = sheet.batch_update(body)
        pprint(res)
    except gspread.exceptions.APIError as gea:
        pprint(gea.args[0], width=100)
```

All the documentation states that "tabColor" should be a Color object (as shown above with a dict of red, green, and blue). There is also an optional alpha.

There is also a "tabColorStyle" parameter, but it too is looking for a color.

I have tried setting "tabColor" to an empty dict, `{}`, RGB to 0 each, and RGB to -1 each. All end up just turning the color black.

There is no mention of a `.clear` option.

So how do I remove the color once it has been set?

Here is a link to the [Google Sheet API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate) and [Sheet properties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#SheetProperties) where I've been looking up how the request should look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to reset the tab colors of sheets in a Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using gspread.

#### Modification point:

- In this case, I think that to use the value of `fields` is an important point. When `"fields": "tabColor"` is used for the request body of the method of batchUpdate, the property of `tabColor` is modified. In that case, in order to reset the tab color, `tabColor` is not included in `properties`. By this, the tab color is reset.

When above point is reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheets = spreadsheet.worksheets()
body = {"requests": [{
    "updateSheetProperties": {
        "properties": {
            "sheetId": e.id,
        },
        "fields": "tabColor"
    }
} for e in sheets]}
spreadsheet.batch_update(body)
```

- In this sample script, the tab colors of all sheets in the Google Spreadsheet are reset.

#### Note:

- When you want to reset the tab color of one of sheets in the Google Spreadsheet, please use the following request body.

  ```
    body = {"requests": [{
        "updateSheetProperties": {
            "properties": {
                "sheetId": sheetId, # Please set the sheet ID.
            },
            "fields": "tabColor"
        }
    }]}
  ```

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batchupdate#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatesheetpropertiesrequest)